# How do I make a simple http response to a stream

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, http

I'm trying to write a simple http server as a part of an application. It needs to respond to Http requests submitted with ajax on 127.0.0.1:someport with a simple text response. A javascript app will poll (or eventually longpoll) for information on the local users actions.

At the moment I've got an httpListener that calls the following as part of its callback processing:

```
    private void ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        var stream = context.Response.OutputStream;
        var resp = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a test response" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "\r\n\r\n");
        stream.Write(resp, 0, resp.Length);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

Which provides a result if called from the browser, but an error if called with $.ajax.

What is the minimum I need to return to get a sucess response to a query such as

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:12345/',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#res').html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert(textStatus);
        }

    }
    );
```

Edit:
I believe I have avoided the cross site scripting issues by running

```
 netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:12345/app user=domain\user
```

and can trace that the ProcessRequest is called

Comment: What is the error ?
What kind of http request are you sending with ajax ?

Comment: Are you running your test HTML from a file:// URL or from a URL hosted under localhost:12345?

Comment: try using Fiddler to see what the ajax response is

Comment: good points. The ProcessRequest is running in a desktop app. The idea is that the desktop app can instruct the webpage to track it and locate relevant data on the intranet with ajax requests. Therefore it needs to be served from the intranet. I avoid the cross site isssue with netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:12345/app user=domain\user and can trace that the ProcessRequest is called. However I might have to try jsonp just in case this is relevant. The sample request is above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your web service works fine.  If you're calling it from a file URL, however, your document will not be able to call any URLs hosted under localhost:12345 because it's considered cross-domain.  Try hosting the HTML and JavaScript under the same web site; you may see more success doing so.

Comment: I avoid the cross site isssue with netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:12345/app user=domain\user and can trace that the ProcessRequest is called.

Comment: OK - turns out that my server gets called inspite of the cross site script, but the results are not returned - instead textStatus ="Error" and nothing in either of the other fields. By using JSONP it just works.